# Access violation when writing to a Fortran allocatable array

Tags: fortran, allocatable-array

```
Program Main

Implicit None
Integer, Parameter :: iwp = SELECTED_Real_KIND(15)
Integer, allocatable :: Num(:)

Num(1)=1

......

End Program Main
```

When I use allocatable to define a void array 'num' and then run the program, it reveals that error as below

> (1)"First-chance exception at 0x00B21147 in Index.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x00000004"
>
> (2)"If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be
>   safely continued"

[image]

Comment: Please copy error messages as text so that they are searchable.

Comment: The array needs to be allocated first. Try to compile with full debugging settings of your compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array `Num` needs to be allocated first. For example

```
 allocate(Num(1:10))
```

end then you can use indexes from 1 to 10 for setting values and reading them.